# I'm not able to add passwordless entry to a new user on EC2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, user-management, ssh-keys

I'm trying to add a deploy user to a EC2 instance to work with capistrano.  I've been able to add passwordless entry for user ubuntu, but it's not working with "deploy".  I'm setting up this user as follows:

```
adduser --system --home /home/deploy --shell /bin/bash --ingroup nogroup deploy
chmod u+w /etc/sudoers
echo "deploy  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
chmod u-w /etc/sudoers
```

I then copy the authorized keys

```
cp /root/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and restart ssh

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

But then when I try to sign in from my local machine like:

```
 ssh -v -i ec2-keypair deploy@domain.com
```

I still get a request for a password. Any ideas?

Comment: Output of `ssh -vv`.  Show the permissions of .ssh, and the authorized_keys.

Comment: Is "ec2-keypair" the public key or the private key?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be safer generating a new keypair for your deploy user rather than reusing the root one.

As you don't mention it, the first thing to check is the ownership & permissions of the `authorized_keys` file, if it is not owned by the deploy user or has `w` for group/other then ssh will fall back on Password authentication.

You can disable `PasswordAuthentication` in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PasswordAuthentication=no
```

You can try this manually with

```
ssh -v -o PasswordAuthentication=no -i ec2-keypair deploy@domain.com
```

before making changes to your configuration.